# Deplopyment Error on Vercel: Cannot find module '/vercel/workpath0/.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a `package.json` script like:

```json
{
 "export": "next export",
 "build": "next build && npm run export && npm run build:rss",
 "build:rss": "node ./.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js",
 "start": "next start",
}
```

It has `build:rss` which points to `./.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js` but it cannot find it on Vercel. How do I point it correctly on Vercel? I get the following error & cannot deploy my site:

```sh
> node ./.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js
15:14:05.786 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
15:14:05.786 throw err;
15:14:05.786 ^
15:14:05.786 Error: Cannot find module '/vercel/workpath0/.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js'
15:14:05.786 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
15:14:05.786 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
15:14:05.786 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
15:14:05.786 at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
```

I tried asking Vercel support but they said:

> I recommend doing something like this → https://github.com/pacocoursey/paco/blob/master/package.json. I'm afraid we do not provide complete code-level support for users on the Hobby plan.

Not sure the link is relevant :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change `server` to `serverless` to make it work on Vercel :)